# How do I add a image to the canvas element and draw on it?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I have found quite a few answers on stackoverflow but they no longer work with ionic and angular.

My first hurdle is copying the image to the canvas.  I cannot seen to copy my image to my canvas

Here is my html

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Original Image:</p>
    <img id="originalPhoto" src="https://preview.ibb.co/jnW4Qz/Grumpy_Cat_920x584.jpg" width=400 height=400 />
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

.ts

```
drawOnPhoto() { 
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log("canvas", canvas); // returns null
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  console.log("ctx",ctx); //returns null
  const img = document.getElementById("originalPhoto");
  console.log("img", img); // returns null
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  /*
  img, error
  Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 
  'HTMLCanvasElement': height, width, captureStream, getContext, 
  and 2 more.
  */
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur?

Comment: the const img returns a null and the ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); gives me the error  Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 
  'HTMLCanvasElement': height, width, captureStream, getContext, 
  and 2 more.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(document.getElementById("canvas"))` presents? Maybe there is no element with "canvas" id?

Comment: Turns this code is not even close.  I have it importing and will post complete code of adding image and drawing on image when complete

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that works with an ionic capacitor project.  I have a base64 image as a background and drawing tools on second layer

html

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let color of colors" [style.background]="color" class="color-block" tappable
          (click)="selectColor(color)"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedColor">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let color of colors" class="ion-text-center">
          <ion-radio [value]="color"></ion-radio>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-radio-group>

    <ion-range min="2" max="20" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="lineWidth">
      <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="brush"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="brush"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>

    <canvas #imageCanvas (touchstart)="startDrawing($event)" (touchmove)="moved($event)" (touchend)="endDrawing()"> </canvas>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

scss

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 178, 178);
}

.color-block {
  height: 40px;
}
```

ts

```
export class QuestionPhotosPage {
  @ViewChild('imageCanvas', { static: false }) canvas: any;
  canvasElement: any;
  saveX: number;
  saveY: number;
  selectedColor = '#9e2956';
  colors = [ '#9e2956', '#c2281d', '#de722f', '#edbf4c', '#5db37e', '#459cde', '#4250ad', '#802fa3' ];
  drawing = false;
  lineWidth = 5;

constructor(private platform: Platform) {}

// used for changing color of brush
selectColor(color) { this.selectedColor = color }

// used to load the background photo and prepare canvas
drawOnPhoto(file: { data: any; }) {
  this.file = file.data; // I'm using a base64 jpeg here
  setTimeout(() => { // added timeout to let the photo finish loading 
    // Set the Canvas Element and its size
    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.canvasElement.width = this.platform.width() + '';
    this.canvasElement.height = 200;
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = this.file; // this is the background image you want to use
    let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    background.onload = () => { ctx.drawImage(background,0,0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);  }
  }, 250);
}

// sets initial drawing point
startDrawing(ev) {
  this.drawing = true;
  let canvasPosition = this.canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.saveX = ev.touches[0].pageX - canvasPosition.x;
  this.saveY = ev.touches[0].pageY - canvasPosition.y;
}

// listens for movement and adds points and joins 
moved(ev) { 
  console.log("this.lineWidth", this.lineWidth)
  if (!this.drawing) return;
  var canvasPosition = this.canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX - canvasPosition.x;
  let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY - canvasPosition.y;
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectedColor;
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.saveX, this.saveY);
  ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  this.saveX = currentX;
  this.saveY = currentY;
}

// when finger removed stops the drawing
endDrawing() { this.drawing = false }
```